# How to Compare Two ImageViews?

Tags: android, background, drawable

I want to check if two imageViews match or not , by getting their background from the Drawable .

i did use this way :

```
     if (imgView1.getBackground().getConstantState()
    .equals(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.myImage)
    .getConstantState())
     &&
    imgView2.getBackground().getConstantState()
.equals(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.myImage)
    .getConstantState()))
        {


        // do something 
        }
```

**it works great on API 23 and API 24** , but not working with API 21 and API 26 ?
is there another way to make it work for all android versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try comparing BitmapDrawable of both of them :

```
  Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgView1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)imgView2.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

  if(bitmap == bitmap2)
     {
//Code blcok
       }
```

Comment: there's something wrong with your example idk why , when i replace imgView1 with my imageview Variable Name it's not working , should i use it like this : imgView1.getBackground() ?

Comment: Sorry , you shoud rather use :  Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgView1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

Comment: works great! but still need to know what picture that they both using ? is it apple ? or orange ? so when i try to get their current background , it doesn't work with API 26  or API 21

Comment: i got it , i just need to getBitmap of My image that saved in my Drawable. and compare it with my imageview's current image.

Comment: Nice , can you please share the solution's code : it will be helpful