# How to compare images in selected ImageView objects?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I'm trying to make a basic candy crush game. I have 9x9 grid layout to put `imageviews.Images` mixed on every execution. For now there are two images when I run the algorithms correctly, I will redound them. If selected imageviews contain same images, user will get 10 points per selected image.Problem is how can I compare and select many imageviews? These ImageViews have onclick buttons but how can I compare them?

Here's what I tried

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView scoreText;
    ImageView imageView1,imageView2,imageView3,imageView4,imageView5,
            imageView6, imageView7,imageView8,imageView9;
    ImageView[]imageArray;
    int[]images;
    //Handler handler;
    //Runnable runnable;
    Drawable x,y;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView1=findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView2=findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView3=findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageView4=findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        imageView5=findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        imageView6=findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        imageView7=findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        imageView8=findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        imageView9=findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
        images= new int[]{R.drawable.grapes,R.drawable.lemon};
        imageArray= new ImageView[]{imageView1, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4,
                imageView5, imageView6, imageView7, imageView8, imageView9};
        ImageSet();
    }
    public void ImageSet()
    {

        for(int j=0;j<imageArray.length;j++)
        {
            Random r =new Random();
            int i=r.nextInt(2-0);
            imageArray[j].setImageResource(images[i]);
        }
    }
    public void image1(View view)
    {

    }
    public void image2(View view)
    {

    }
    public void image3(View view)
    {

    }
    public void image4(View view)
    {

    }
    public void image5(View view)
    {

    }
    public void image6(View view)
    {

    }
    public void image7(View view)
    {

    }
    public void image8(View view)
    {

    }
    public void image9(View view)
    {

    }

 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Compare Two ImageViews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749651/how-to-compare-two-imageviews)

Comment: used a getId() method to compare the Object

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is creating imageViews dinamically in code and add it to layout for example:

```
       for(int i=0;i<ar.lenght;i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(activity);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(ar[i]);
            imageView.setOnClickListener((view)->{});
            yourLayout.addView(imageView);
        }
```

Or you can inflate them with your properties. And you can add tag or id to identify them. But in you case you should to store in your class a last number and compares it with current clicked image and after two clicks nullify it.

Maybe something like this would help...

```
        Integer lastClickedImageId;
        for(int i=0;i<ar.lenght;i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(activity);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(ar[i]);
            imageView.setId(i);
            imageView.setOnClickListener((view)->{
                if(lastClickedImageId==null){
                    lastClickedImageId=imageView.getId();
                } else {
                    if(lastClickedImageId.equals(imageView.getId())){
                        //TODO hide cards?
                        lastClickedImageId=null;
                    }
                }
            });
```